# Can't use a deprecated API in PHP 5.5

Tags: php, curl

I am attempting to upload an image to Instagram using a reverse-engineered Instagram API. In my code, I have this segment:

```
$data = [
  'device_timestamp' => time(),
  'photo' => '@' . $filename
];
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

But this throws this error:

```
Deprecated: curl_setopt(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead
```

I know that I could use a CURLFile instead, but the Instagram API doesn't support this. I need to use the so-called "@filename API" from PHP 5.5. How can I do this? Is there a workaround for this deprecation?

Comment: How could that Instagram API care how the request got constructed?

Comment: *"... but the Instagram API doesn't support this"* - the server won't care what client API you use - it's just a better PHP API, maybe try giving it a go :)